# Insert Build Number or Drop Locatoin into a table "After" the Build is Created

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, tfs, msbuild

How can I create a Post-Deployment script to insert the Build Number or Drop Location into a table of the database that was deployed? Have seen lots of articles on how to use SQLCMD variables or other variables to override MSBuild variables to use in creating a Build.  But what I need to do is grab the Build Number or Drop Location "after" the Build is complete and write that information into a table.

Here is the script I'm trying to implement as a Post-deployment script:

USE [COPCOVDB]
GO

DECLARE @DropLocation varchar(255)
SET @DropLocation='$(TF_BUILD_DROP_LOCATION)'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Build_Number] ([Build_Location]) VALUES (@DropLocation)

Instead of inserting the $(TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION) value which should be the path to where the deployment files are, it is inserting the actual string value of '$(TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION) ....

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes around the variable?
IE instead of @DropLocation='$(TF_BUILD_DROP_LOCATION)' use @DropLocation=$(TF_BUILD_DROP_LOCATION)

Comment: Moved comments and removed web hook answer. So you are trying to run an SQL script referenced in a XAML build definitions Post-build script? is that correct? Or are you adding the variable to a database project that's deploying? Not using powershell at all here?

Comment: Correct, just plain old Post-Deployment SQL script in the XAML build, not trying to read a variable value to "configure" any Build value or edit the definition, just want to read the "Drop Location" value somehow in a Post-Deployment script that simply is a SQL INSERT statement into a table that will hold the value of the Drop Location. Will try without the single quotes as you suggest.

Comment: Removing single quotes did not work, the Build failed with error message that the Variable was not defined. D:\BUILDS\629\HUB\FORM.3.DEV.DB.COPCOVDB\SOURCES\SCRIPTS\POST-DEPLOYMENT\INSERT_BUILD_LOCATION.SQL (5): Variable TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION is not defined.

Comment: I think that variable may have been removed in 2015 -> https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/define/variables

Comment: Try these for giggles -> $(BUILD_DROPLOCATION) or $(Build.DropLocation)

Comment: I don't understand why there is such inconsistency between the docs and the versions but I do believe BUILD_DROPLOCATION is now the correct variable. http://www.deliveron.com/blog/initiating-vnext-releases-release-management-2015-tfs-build-2015/

Comment: Ok thanks!  Using TFS 2012, but will try the other variable variations.